# Query user details from EventRelation object

Tags: apex, soql

I need to be able to pull certain user attributes from the `User` object where the user is listed as an invitee for an event. I checked and could not find any true relation between the `EventRelation` object and `User` object. What is the relationship that ties them together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [SOAP Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm) on `EventRelation` it seems you are looking for the `RelationId` field.

> **RelationId** - Contains the ID of the person (User, Contact, or Lead) or the resource invited to an event.

You can select only `EventRelation` records relevant to `User` records as follows:

```
SELECT Id FROM EventRelation WHERE Relation.Type = 'User'
```

You can select `User` specific fields using [SOQL Polymorphism](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2012/09/soql-polymorphism-or-how-i-learned-to-love-the-polymorphic-relationship.html) with a [TYPEOF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm) clause as follows:

```
SELECT
    TYPEOF Relation
        WHEN User THEN ManagerId, Manager.Name
    END
FROM EventRelation
```

Comment: How can you only query where RelationId are users? Can you provide me a sample query of how to use the RelationId to get the user’s manager

Comment: That's a little beyond what you asked in your OP, you might make it a better question by including there. Regardless I added to my answer.

Comment: @SalesforceDeveloper Does this address your needs or do you still have questions?